# Create array from compass sensor value

Tags: javascript, algorithm

creating a web app which shows a sensor value worked so far. But I ended up in far to long functions updating a compass rose.

Basically I have an array with numbers like this:

```
[20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220,240,260,280,300,320,340,360]
```

Giving it a sensor position like 40 I would like to center the array like this:

```
[240,260,280,300,320,340,360,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220]
```

is there a simple way to do that ?
preferably in JavaScript ?

Comment: *"Giving it a sensor position like 40 I would like to center the array like that"* what do you mean by *center the array* ?

Comment: as in the second array shown. Now 40 is the center and the values are shifted clockwise

Comment: What have **YIU** tried so far?

Comment: Used the valid answer here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])
```

**`start` - parameter**

If negative, it will begin that many elements from the end of the array

```js
let array = [20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260, 280, 300, 320, 340, 360]

function rotate(array, value) {
  let start = -(array.length / 2 - array.indexOf(value) - 1);
  return [].concat(array.splice(start), array);
}

console.log(rotate(array, 40))
```

Comment: thanks for that. Worked like charm and looks simply brilliant !

Comment: @user3732793 Welcome. Glad to help